# Why doesn't javascript draw the images on the canvas?

Tags: javascript, image, canvas

I have a problem with drawing images to my canvas. There is no error but still there is no images drawn. Please review the chunk of code and see if you can see what I cannot:

```
function loadPacman(posX, posY) {
    this.posX = posX;
    this.posY = posY;
    pacman = new Image();
    pacman.src="http://www.frogbug.se/pacman/img/naziman.png";
    pacman.addEventListener("load", function(){
            canvas.drawImage(pacman, this.posX, this.posY)
        }, false);
}

function loadGhost(posX, posY) {
    this.posX = posX;
    this.posY = posY;
    ghost = new Image();
    ghost.src="http://www.frogbug.se/pacman/img/ghost.png";
    ghost.addEventListener("load", function(){
            canvas.drawImage(ghost, this.posX, this.posY)
        }, false);
}
```

And this is my function that loads when the page loads:

```
function onLoad() {
    var xy = document.getElementById('canvas');
    canvas = xy.getContext('2d');
    //calculate the x and y for canvas
    x = xy.width;
    y = xy.height;

    //divide the width and length of the canvas to get small cubes
    //which is 40x40
    xtile = Math.floor(x/40);
    ytile = Math.floor(y/40);

    //draw lines around the canvas
    canvas.strokeRect(0, 0, x, y);

    //the array for the map
    var map = getMapArray();

    //draw the map
    drawMap(map);
    //fillCanvas("0010", 0, 40, 40, 40);

    //load the ghost and pacman
    loadPacman(0, 0);
    loadGhost((xtile*40)-40, (ytile*40)-40);
}
```

Thanks in advance!
You can view the full source and so on here:
http://www.picturds.com/pacman_serious/

Comment: Btw I know my code is a bit sloppy, but I'll clean it up later. :)

Comment: You may have some issues in understanding how `this` works. Have a quick read: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/this.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove `this` from `this.posX` and `this.posY` in the load callback. `this` in that context is the image element, not the same `this` as when you assign to `this.posX` (which is `window`).

http://jsfiddle.net/5dkx4/